# Unsupervised ML approach for single column dataset

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset consist of product descriptions that needs to classify.
I am new to ML. As per my understanding I should follow route like,
1. Apply clustering to the dataset
2. Apply labels to identified clustered data.(labels are the classes in which products can be classified further)
3. Now Using known label, apply supervised learning to get accuracy and find discrepancies

I found many examples for such problem statement, but all of them has multiple attributes in a dataset to plot graph and later create clusters. Guide me to build plot for dataset with single attribute.

Comment: Curious if you can provide a sample of your data, and what you think a cluster of single feature data might look like? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Eventually I want to divide dataset into chunks with similarities in product description. Similarities can be like common words etc among descriptions

Comment: That clarification is why we ask for sample data. That shouldn;t be thought of as a single feature, just a feature engineering problem. See the [sklearn docs for working with text data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) for options like bag-of-words, tf-idf, countvectorizers, etc to turn your documents into a full feature set

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the suggested link